# Iterate and compare nth element with the rest of elements in list

Tags: python

I have a list of integers and have to check if all of the integers to the right (so, from each int to the end of the list) are strictly smaller than the one I'm iterating over.

E.g. for `[42, 7, 12, 9, 2, 5]` I have to compare if `42` is bigger than `[7, 12, 9, 2, 5]`, if `7` is bigger than `[12, 9, 2, 5]` and so on to the end of the list.

The function has to return the amount of numbers that are bigger than the rest of the list, including the last one - as there's no bigger number after it.

Code I have now:

```
def count_dominators(items):

    if len(items)< 2:
        return len(items)
    

    dominators_count = 0
    for ind, el in enumerate(items[0:-1]):
        
        if el > items[ind+1]:
            dominators_count += 1
            pass
```

I've tried iterating with nested `for`-loops, using `enumerate()` and iterating over that using `itertools.combinations()`, and combining those ways, but to no avail - I usually get `TypeError`s linked to iterating (e.g list index out of range, even though I used slicing to avoid it).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `enumerate` to iterate over the items with their indices (as you're already doing), and then using `all` to iterate over all the items after a given item, and `sum` to sum all of the `all` results:

```
>>> def count_dominators(items):
...     return sum(all(n > m for m in items[i+1:]) for i, n in enumerate(items))
...
>>> count_dominators([42, 7, 12, 9, 2, 5])
4
```

Another approach would be to compare to the `max` of the remaining items, although then you need to special-case the end of the list (`all` returns `True` for an empty list, but `max` will raise an exception):

```
>>> def count_dominators(items):
...     return sum(n > max(items[i+1:]) for i, n in enumerate(items[:-1])) + 1
...
>>> count_dominators([42, 7, 12, 9, 2, 5])
4
```